# upload image in django unit test

Tags: python, django

im trying to upload an image to an ImageField in my unit test cant figure out the error

here is my code (this one works fine in other unit test with FileField)

```
request = self.factory.put(
    '/api/1.0/accounts/artlover/',
    {'profile_img': SimpleUploadedFile('foo.jpg', b'foo content')}
)
force_authenticate(request, self.artlover)
view = AccountViewSet.as_view({'put': 'update'})
resp = view(request, slug='artlover')
self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
self.assertFalse(resp.data.get('is_artist'))
```

getting this error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ben/aktweb/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/ImageFile.py", line  100, in __init__
self._open()
File "/home/ben/aktweb/lib/python3.4/site-packages/PIL/TgaImagePlugin.py", line 62, in _open
depth = i8(s[16])
IndexError: index out of range
```

and when i try working with real image

```
img = ('/home/ben/aktweb/7.jpg')
with open(img) as infile:
    request = self.factory.put(
        '/api/1.0/accounts/artist/',
        {'profile_img': SimpleUploadedFile('7.jpg', infile.read())}
    )
    force_authenticate(request, self.artist)
    view = AccountViewSet.as_view({'put': 'update'})
    resp = view(request, slug='artist')
    self.assertEqual(resp.status_code, 200)
    self.assertTrue(resp.data.get('is_artist'))
```

end with this

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/home/ben/aktweb/django/accounts/tests/test_views.py", line 163, in test_update
{'profile_img': SimpleUploadedFile('7.jpg', infile.read())}
File "/home/ben/aktweb/lib/python3.4/codecs.py", line 319, in decode
(result, consumed) = self._buffer_decode(data, self.errors, final)
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0xff in position 0: invalid start byte
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Open the image file with binary mode (`b`):
2. Just pass the file object as value of the dictionary.

---

```
img = '/home/ben/aktweb/7.jpg'
with open(img, 'rb') as infile:
    request = self.factory.put(
        '/api/1.0/accounts/artist/',
        {'profile_img': infile}
    )
    ...
```

Comment: that work even with SimpleUploadedFile thanks a lot !